# Initialization of static const member variables based on each other

Tags: c++, c++11

Is this safe to assume that `A` is initialized to 1 when initializing B and C here?

```
struct Test {
  static const int A = 1;
  static const int B = A + 1;
  static const int C = B + 1;
};

int main() {
  printf("%i %i %i\n", Test::A, Test::B, Test::C);  ==> 1 2 3
}
```

what about for non-integral static members

```
struct Test2 {
  constexpr static const Test A = Test();
  constexpr static const Test B = A;
  constexpr static const Test C = B;
};
```

`clang` `-Wall` issues no warnings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They will be initialized in the order of **definition** in given translation unit and before any other objects or variables.

Comment: And if they're defined in different translation units?  (Actually, in this case, since only static initialization is involved, it's safe regardless of the configuration.  But you're right with regards to the general case.)

Comment: @JamesKanze If they're defined in different translation units the initialization order is unpredictable. See "static initialization fiasco": http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/static-init-order.html

Comment: @DieterLücking Sort of.  Since the initializations in question are constant expressions, resulting in static initialization, there is no initialization order.

Comment: @Marian Not in this case.  I'll often make a special effort for my global variables to be statically initialized, precisely because it avoids any order of initialization issues.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe.  In this case, the initialization of `A` is static, so
`A` can be used as an integral constant expression.  Which then
propagates to `B`.  When you declare the members, they will be
initialized statically, to what the compiler has evaluated (i.e.
`0` and `1`), before the program even starts.

If they aren't initialized statically (which is only legal in
C++11), for any reason whatever, then they will be initialized
in the order the definitions appear in the source file, if they
are defined in the same source file.  If they are not defined in
the same source file, then the order they are initialized is
unspecified.

Concerning your second example: if they are really `constexpr`,
there are still only constant expressions involved, so
everything will be decided at compile time, and the members will
be statically initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Objects with static storage duration are always zero-initialized prior to anything else:

> Variables with static storage duration (3.7.1) or thread storage duration (3.7.2) shall be zero-initialized (8.5) before any other initialization takes place.

[3.6.2§2]

Therefore any constant or dynamic initialization may assume that all other objects with static storage duration are at least zero-initialized.

Note that this does *not* give any guarantees for anything other than zero-initialization!

Comment: But there's no dynamic initialization in his example.

Comment: I elaborated, it just took a second to get the exact wording right ;)